# webbased sdk for netgen fingerprint recognition argent on asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i'm working on asp.net so need SDK netgen fingerprint recognition argent on asp.net

i tried with following code,popup is not coming to capture the finger print
            uint ret1 = m_NBioAPI.Enroll(out m_FIR, null);
           // uint ret1 = m_NBioAPI.Capture(out m_FIR, NBioAPI.Type.TIMEOUT.DEFAULT, null);
            if (ret1 == BioAPI.Error.NONE)
            {
            uint ret = m_NBioAPI.GetTextFIRFromHandle(m_hNewFIR, out m_textFIR, true);
            }

Please help me its very argent